# How to animate an HTML5 SVG path's filter for a glow / blur / shadow effect?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to reproduce the CSS3 SVG "filter:drop-shadow" effect on hover for an SVG path's filter. I've seen ways to alter the stdDeviation attribute with the [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) plugin but am looking for a solution without the need of a separate plugin.

Below is as close as I can seem to get, and I'm not sure why my animateBlur() function isn't incrementing the stdDeviation. Anyone know what's going wrong or know of some clever tricks that will make this effect work?

https://jsfiddle.net/webmw/p6vsc5y3/

```js
function animateBlur() {
 jQuery({ n: 0 }).animate({ n: 7 }, {
  duration: 500,
  step: function(now, fx) {
   var increment = now;
   console.log(increment);
   return increment;
  }
 });
}

$("svg path").mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).attr("filter","url(#f1)");
      $("feGaussianBlur").attr("stdDeviation",animateBlur());
      
}).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr("filter");
});
```

```css
html,body,svg {height:100%}
body {background:cornsilk;}
img,svg path {cursor:pointer;}

.dropshadow {
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.dropshadow {
 -webkit-filter: none;
  filter:none;
  height:150px;
}
.dropshadow:hover {
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.9));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.9));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Easy to hover / animate drop-shadow on regular SVGs:</p>
<img class="dropshadow" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Star_wars2.svg" />

<p>But how to animate with the same effect on an "SVG path" object?</p>
<svg viewBox="90 -10 300 200">

  <defs>

    <filter id="f1" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="0" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="7" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  
  </defs>
  
  <path d="m 156.29028,68.019096 c 4.67931,-1.988204 -0.12418,-10.666555 10.32783,-11.26589 1.83984,-0.1055 3.04194,0.379201 5.51291,0.764346 0.069,-1.457882 0.39368,-7.513956 0.18783,-9.0114 -0.20581,-1.497443 -2.17888,-0.886775 -3.88749,-1.604662 -2.9137,-2.004347 -3.60967,-4.508091 -4.90279,-7.066947 -1.43623,-2.842048 -2.74829,-5.873666 -3.08935,-9.039685 -0.38465,-3.570722 1.01485,-7.116117 1.23297,-10.703361 1.08612,-0.941004 2.17224,-1.882009 3.25836,-2.823013 -0.40015,-1.882008 -0.8003,-3.764017 -1.20045,-5.646025 -1.881,-1.240819 -5.47796,-1.429412 -4.39448,-4.3669975 0.12147,-1.7496304 0.24294,-3.4992608 0.36441,-5.2488912 -1.71492,0 -3.42985,0 -5.14477,0 1.55912,1.9274484 0.0233,3.2815506 -1.44728,4.4870662 -4.33942,4.6764345 -17.98037,9.8959195 -21.082,8.7530705 -0.2683,-2.332216 -2.37086,2.393413 -3.28353,0.596362 1.34212,2.644214 0.18957,5.899268 -2.70665,6.345448 -2.3295,-1.915206 -4.30895,-5.103085 -7.56114,-3.218799 -3.12217,0.22867 -5.92518,-1.40308 -8.60189,-2.759866 -1.57069,-0.466831 -4.99248,0.07945 -1.89293,1.516781 2.16684,0.932005 4.2283,1.962703 3.53082,4.572657 0,1.793017 0,3.586035 0,5.379053 3.17614,1.071151 2.57339,6.821091 5.18841,6.882203 6.54256,0.152896 6.52233,0.756564 8.9075,3.546429 5.61657,6.569528 3.49195,14.688396 5.04055,24.775964 0.71231,4.639968 4.29374,10.456375 8.59444,10.753658 2.6538,0.183442 4.77082,-4.041744 6.62733,-5.400138 6.44957,-2.977631 3.60533,1.641529 10.42139,-0.217363 z"></path>
  
  <path d="m 260.769,66.023156 c 3.8349,-4.788158 8.79324,-8.576249 12.7991,-13.224205 1.75034,-2.886256 3.43676,-4.132595 5.93865,-4.863527 1.36048,-1.366469 0.7359,-3.785632 1.10386,-5.678447 -0.76366,-0.838347 -1.35457,-2.029861 -2.22664,-2.646575 -0.99259,-0.08879 -2.12712,0.169001 -3.03839,-0.118352 -1.30495,-1.404354 -2.86845,-2.614797 -4.1339,-4.011836 -2.15241,-6.618271 -4.5275,-13.195742 -5.71384,-20.074944 -1.99173,-9.307097 -2.15055,-5.084229 -4.23803,-2.694703 -1.89331,2.261054 -3.97742,4.394485 -5.75197,6.734975 -2.17919,4.369109 -4.35839,8.738218 -6.53758,13.107327 -1.71492,1.11744 -3.42985,2.234883 -5.14477,3.352328 -1.4828,-0.470312 -2.96182,-1.251763 -4.44692,-1.533208 -4.79877,2.860083 -3.39481,-3.099681 -4.61322,-1.645561 -0.83557,0.646548 -3.16443,2.417752 -4.33214,2.171548 -2.60394,0.20477 -3.7511,-0.08068 -6.2436,-0.757161 -3.3e-4,1.040982 -0.36041,4.077489 1.15977,3.597984 1.14715,0.14345 2.47104,-0.492629 3.62131,0.0082 3.61471,1.043297 7.56377,3.356319 10.11497,7.322839 4.58458,7.718114 4.36102,8.17007 5.13813,13.923417 0.58204,4.309185 2.91437,2.859459 4.04981,4.539599 1.2544,1.856164 1.73521,3.698395 2.9847,6.021742 1.82746,3.202236 1.66695,4.37289 3.5547,4.410115 1.50738,0.02972 2.06302,-2.206341 2.97507,-3.406861 1.09428,-1.440386 1.85013,-3.122803 2.98093,-4.534694 z"></path>
  
</svg>
```

### Edit

If it is impractical or even impossible to do what I'm asking without a plugin, please let me know as I am not 100% opposed to the idea of using TweenLite or TweenMax.

Comment: Why would you reinvent the wheel if you already have a light-weight library like TweenLite (and the slightly heavier TweenMax) at your disposal? These libraries also make it easier to have your animations work cross-browser.

Comment: Great question newplayer65. Typically in jQuery there are several ways to skin a cat, and I thought this concept seemed simple enough for basic jQuery but maybe it isn't. If it is impractical or even impossible to do what I'm asking without a plugin, I am not necessarily opposed to the idea to use TweenLite or TweenMax. I will edit my question and include that info... thank you...

Comment: It's not impossible, nor impractical to make animations with pure CSS or JS or jQuery. That's how the animation libraries were made. Though you never mentioned what browser you've tested your code on, and that matters a lot as well. It's going to be more of a pain than anything to make your hand-written CSS animations work cross-browser.